# Using JQ to create a JSON file from a list of files

Tags: json, bash, jq

I want to create a JSON file from a list of files like:

```
$ ls -r *
folder1/
   file1.pdf
   file2.pdf
   file3.pdf
folder2/

   file4.pdf
   file5.pdf
   file6.pdf
```

I want a json file that looks like this:

```
{
  'folder1' : [ 'file1.pdf', 'file2.pdf', 'file3.pdf' ],
  'folder2' : [ 'file4.pdf', 'file5.pdf', 'file6.pdf' ]
}
```

For now I am able to create the list of files with `jq` but not sure how to name them. This is what I am doing now:

```
$ ls folder | jq -R -s 'split("\n") -[""]'
[ 
   "file1.pdf",
   "file2.pdf",
   "file3.pdf"
]
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

PS. Additionally, I need to include a prefix in the name of files. I can try to do it with `sed` but if maybe there is an easier way to do it here, that would be even better.

Comment: Are there other directories inside `folder1` and `folder2`?

Comment: @oguzismail no, no other directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't [parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Pass `folder1/file1.pdf`, `folder1/file2.pdf`, etc. to JQ as positional arguments instead, and parse them in there.

```
jq -n 'reduce ($ARGS.positional[] / "/") as [$k, $v] (.; .[$k] += ["prefix-\($v)"])' --args */*
```